# Android live wallpaper sample getting force closed , Unable to instantiate service

Tags: android, opengl-es, live-wallpaper

I trying to run a  some tutorial samples for android live wall paper but always got this error

> 09-28 16:13:30.729: E/AndroidRuntime(408): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to instantiate service
>   net.markguerra.android.glwallpaperexample.MyWallpaperService:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   net.markguerra.android.glwallpaperexample.MyWallpaperService in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/net.markguerra.android.glwallpaperexample-1.apk]

This  is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="net.markguerra.android.glwallpaperexample"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <service android:label="@string/service_label" android:name=".MyWallpaperService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
                android:resource="@xml/myglwallpaper" />
        </service>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

</manifest>
```

Wallpaper service i created

```
package net.markguerra.android.glwallpaperexample;

import net.rbgrn.android.glwallpaperservice.*;

// Original code provided by Robert Green
// http://www.rbgrn.net/content/354-glsurfaceview-adapted-3d-live-wallpapers

public class MyWallpaperService extends GLWallpaperService {
    public MyWallpaperService() {
        super();
    }

    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        MyEngine engine = new MyEngine();
        return engine;
    }

    class MyEngine extends GLEngine {
        MyRenderer renderer;
        public MyEngine() {
            super();
            // handle prefs, other initialization
            renderer = new MyRenderer();
            setRenderer(renderer);
            setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
        }

        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (renderer != null) {
                renderer.release();
            }
            renderer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

this is my projrct structure

[image]

I cant figure out whats going wrong in it, Whats the error ? 
Any suggestions will be a great help for me

found some related questions on stack but not related to live wallpaper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include `GLWallpaperService.jar` in `libs` folder.

Comment: Thank you Tecigo, GLWallpaperService.jar is already thier in the lib

Comment: Then remove the jar you have highlighted in the project structure.

Comment: it must be `libs` not `lib` or am I mistaken? With `libs` you should see a small `a` on the folder like `res` or `bin` have...

Answer (score 2):

it must be libs not lib or am I mistaken? With libs you should see a small a on the folder like res or bin have...